# How to select fields and count for each field in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have an SQL table called messages I want to select `DISTINCT` user names from table who are sending any message to the recipient who had the id ($uid) and also select `COUNT(message)` for every sender, using a one line query.

I've tried this code:

```
$query="SELECT DISTINCT clientname,user_id,user1pic, COUNT("SELECT id FROM messages WHERE clientname=clientname) AS counted FROM messages WHERE receiver=$uid and status='unread' ";
$messages=mysqli_query($cnx,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($cnx,$messages)){

echo '<a class="example" > '.$row['clieenter code herentname'].''.$row['counted'].'</a>' ;}
if(mysqli_num_rows($cnx,$messages)<=0){
    echo '<a class="example" href="#">You Have No Messages</a>' ;
}
```

Comment: Please make this a coherent question by including sample table data along with the expected output.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i was wondering if there is a way to count the messages of each sender in the same query line

Comment: This query is likely to have a SQL injection vulnerability in it - do not go live with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
  clientname,
  user_id,
  user1pic, 
  COUNT(1) AS counted 
FROM 
  messages 
WHERE 
  receiver=:uid 
  and status='unread'
Group by
  clientname,
  user_id,
  user1pic;
```

I have replaced your inline PHP variable with a parameter placeholder - please use parameter binding to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Thaaaanks Worked ,